# Kotlin - String from Edittext in DialogFragment don't save in data class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, fragment, dialogfragment

I have one Edittext in DialogFragment and that create a new group. When I press "OK" Group is created but without string.

I try figure out but complitly I don't know where is mistake.

my DialogFragment:

```
class NewCategory(val listener: NewCategoryCreateListener) : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val view = requireActivity()
        val newCategoryView = view.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.new_category, null)
        val txtNewCat = newCategoryView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etNewCategory)
        val newCat = txtNewCat.text.toString()

        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(newCategoryView)
            .setTitle("Create new category")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") {di, i ->
                listener.newCategoryCreate(newCat)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { di, i -> }
            .create()
    }

    interface NewCategoryCreateListener{
        fun newCategoryCreate(text: String)
    }
}
```

my MainFragment:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(), NewCategory.NewCategoryCreateListener {

    private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
    private val binding
        get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var shoppingListViewModel: ShoppingListViewModel
    private lateinit var categoryAdapter: CategoryAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.categoryRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        shoppingListViewModel.allCategories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            updateCategories(it)
        })

        binding.addCategory.setOnClickListener {
            val newCategory = NewCategory(this)
            newCategory.show(childFragmentManager, "NewCategory")
        }
    }


    private fun updateCategories(list: List<Category>) {
        categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(list)
        binding.categoryRV.adapter = categoryAdapter
    }

    override fun newCategoryCreate(text: String) {
        val newCat = Category(text)
        shoppingListViewModel.insertCategory(newCat)
    }

}
```

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your `newCat` string to the text view text when the dialog is created, not when the okay button is hit. So your string is empty.

Try moving `val newCat = txtNewCat.text.toString()` to inside your okay button callback like this:

```
        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(newCategoryView)
            .setTitle("Create new category")
            .setPositiveButton("OK") {di, i ->
                val newCat = txtNewCat.text.toString()
                listener.newCategoryCreate(newCat)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { di, i -> }
            .create()
```

Comment: thank you so much :)